# Creating folder from text

Tags: java

I am getting

```
newDir D:\template_export\template\attachments\processed\enumeration\blocker.gif\enumeration\critical.gif\enumeration\high.gif\enumeration\low.gif\enumeration\major.gif\enumeration\medium.gif\enumeration\minor.gif\enumeration\normal.gif\enumeration\unassigned.gif\enumeration\unassigned2.gif\workflow\close.gif\workflow\defer.gif\workflow\duplicate.gif\workflow\inprogress.gif\workflow\new.gif\workflow\open.gif\workflow\reject.gif\workflow\remind.gif\workflow\reopen.gif\workflow\resolve.gif\workflow\unconfigure.gif\workflow\unresolve.gif\workflow\verify.gif\workflow\wontdo.gif\workflow\works.gif\workitemtype\bug.gif\workitemtype\enhancement.gif\workitemtype\general.gif\workitemtype\task.gif\workitemtype
new directory false
reached
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: D:\template_export\template\attachments\1.gif -> D:\template_export\template\attachments\processed\enumeration\blocker.gif\enumeration\critical.gif\enumeration\high.gif\enumeration\low.gif\enumeration\major.gif\enumeration\medium.gif\enumeration\minor.gif\enumeration\normal.gif\enumeration\unassigned.gif\enumeration\unassigned2.gif\workflow\close.gif\workflow\defer.gif\workflow\duplicate.gif\workflow\inprogress.gif\workflow\new.gif\workflow\open.gif\workflow\reject.gif\workflow\remind.gif\workflow\reopen.gif\workflow\resolve.gif\workflow\unconfigure.gif\workflow\unresolve.gif\workflow\verify.gif\workflow\wontdo.gif\workflow\works.gif\workitemtype\bug.gif\workitemtype\enhancement.gif\workitemtype\general.gif\workitemtype\task.gif\workitemtype\unknown.gifprocess_template_license.htmltemplate.messagestemplate_en_US.messages
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.move(Unknown Source)
    at Test.main(Test.java:60)
Error.
```

My code is :

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File orgDirectory = new File("D://template_export/template/attachments"); // replace this filename 
        // with the path to the folder 
        // that contains the original images

        String fileContent = "";
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(orgDirectory, "attachments.txt")))) {
            for (String line;
            (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
                fileContent += line;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String[] newLocations = fileContent.split(",");
        File[] orgFiles = orgDirectory.listFiles(new FileFilter() {@Override
            public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                return pathname.getPath().endsWith(".gif");
            }
        });
        File destinationFolder = new File("D://template_export/template/attachments/processed");
        if (!destinationFolder.exists()) {

            System.out.println("here" + destinationFolder.mkdir());
        }
        int max = Math.min(orgFiles.length, newLocations.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            String newLocation = newLocations[i];
            int lastIndex = newLocation.lastIndexOf("/");
            if (lastIndex == -1) {
                continue;
            }
            String newDirName = newLocation.substring(0, lastIndex);
            System.out.println("newDirName " + newDirName);

            String newName = newLocation.substring(lastIndex);
            System.out.println("newName " + newName);

            File newDir = new File(destinationFolder, newDirName);
            System.out.println("newDir " + newDir);

            if (!newDir.exists()) {
                System.out.println("new directory " + newDir.mkdir());
            }
            try {
                System.out.println("reached");

                Files.move(orgFiles[i].toPath(), new File(newDir, newName).toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you concat your lines from the file without `,` and then split it into newLocations by `,` (is it possible that you just get one item at this point?)

Answer (score 0):

You're concatenating all the lines of the `attachments.txt` file into a single destination string. Judging from the exception message, it appears that the attachments file does not contain commas at the end of each line. Thus you end up with a destination consisting of a single file name, seemingly in a deeply nested directory.

Instead, I suggest that you read the lines in one at a time into an `ArrayList<String>`, rather than concatenating and later splitting the destinations.

```
ArrayList<String> newLocations = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(orgDirectory, "attachments.txt")))) {
    for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
        newLocations.add(line);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then you can use `newLocations.size()` where you now use `newLocations.length` and use `newLocations.get(i)` where you use `newLocations[i]`.

EDIT: As @griFlo points out in a comment, a simpler alternative to reading the file into a list of lines is:

```
List<String> newLocations = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("attachments.txt"));
```

If the file will not read properly with UTF-8 decoding (which is what the above call will use), or if you're compiling with Java 7, you'll have to use the two-argument version of `readAllLines()`:

```
List<String> newLocations = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("attachments.txt"),
    StandardCharsets.US_ASCII); // or whatever encoding is appropriate
```

Comment: he could use the `Files.readAllLines` method instead  (`List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path));`

Comment: @griFlo - Yes, that's a very good option. I'll update the answer.